# Latitude/Longitude processing to avoid Null Island entries

Tags: entities, javascript, location

I have to display some 8k points on a map rendered by a view on my site.

Since those locations will be updated quite often i decided to use a custom entity (lets call them "Structures"), so i could make all the data heavylifting manually on the db.

I managed to display my Structures locations on a Leaflet Map and everything went fine.

BUT! Some of my Structures don't have a latitude/longitude, and they are stored with a 0,0 value and they are therefore shown in the infamous Null Island.

I could fix this by bounding regions or exluding them from view but i wanted to try something a bit more complex.

What i would like to do is to process my data to call a geocoder in the (0,0) case to ask Google to find location based on address (wich i have).

Where (or when) should i do my scripting?

- On the database, prior to manual import? (simple, but outside-Drupal solution)
- Working with the Entity API to update values? (is it even possible since i'm importing data manually?)
- Right before the data is shown? So with Leaflet API or IP GeoLocation View&Maps?